# Using docker to run a react native app, using expo

Tags: react-native, docker, containers, port

I have a small react native app, and I'm trying to run it using docker. I believe I know what my problem is, but I really can't solve it. My Dockerfile is as such:

```
FROM node:12

WORKDIR /client

COPY package*.json ./

RUN yarn install

RUN yarn global add expo-cli

COPY . .

ENV PORT=8080

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

I built my image, and then tried to run it using: docker run -p 19002:8080 53abf08beb39. Everything looks ok, expo tells me it is running in localhost:19002, and that the app is running in localhost:19000. Despite this, when i try to access these ports, I only see a "this site can't be reached" page. I was told this was because expo is exposing the port, but since it's running in docker, it can only be accessed from inside the container, so I need a way to expose this out of the container to be able to run it on my laptop. How can I achieve this?
Also, if anyone knows how should I create a docker-compose file to run all this, it would be great.